# Instamine not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I put a beacon on my world did the 9x9 and got the haste 2 effect. On my inventory, It says that I have haste 2 but when I mine, it won't let me do the instamine thing that everyone else has. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: are you using the appropriate pickaxe

Comment: Do you have a high efficiency pick?

Comment: What is "instamine"?

Comment: @RayWu breaking blocks at speed on 1 block per gametick, so up to 20 blocks per second. You can for example instamine leaves off a tree using shears. Eff5+Haste2 on diamond or better pick instamines stone.

Answer (score 2):

Instant mining occurs when your mining speed exceeds the hardness of a block by a factor of 30. The equation includes the base speed of the pickaxe, the squared value of your efficiency, and a multiplicative factor based upon your haste.

The Efficiency value is very important. Even with Haste 2, an unenchanted Diamond Pickaxe would be slower than an Efficiency 5 wooden pickaxe.

If you aren’t instant mining and your friends are, it’s likely because you are missing some level of efficiency.

Check out this resource to see what you should be able to instant mine for your given enchantments. It also shows the equations and gives some values for you to work with.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Instant_mining

This resource will explain the concept more in-depth with more numbers.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breaking

Answer (score 0):

I have done a lot of research. And I have made this list:
Wooden Pickaxe : No effects
Stone Pickaxe : No effects
Iron Pickaxe : No effects
Golden Pickaxe : Efficency V on Stone
Diamond Pickaxe : Efficency V on Stone
Netherite Pickaxe : Efficency V on Stone

If you want to test those pickaxes out with options and the code.. [Go check it out](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/572754137574539284/791410966809673748/haste.rar)!